# Python: Sharing variables between classes/objects

Tags: python, oop, class

Ok I have two classes and one is dependent on the other.
So I need to get a variable from the first class and use it in the second.
But the second variable is constantly changing.
Like this:

```
class class1 :
    var1 = 0
    def meth1 (self):
        self.var1 += 1
class class2:
    var2 = class1.var1
    def see (self):
        return self.var2
obj1 = class1()
obj2 = class2()

obj1.meth1()
obj2.see()
```

This would return 0 not 1.
If I say print var1 in class one it prints that changed var.
But when class2 gets it it is still 0...
I guess it is still referring to the old var1.
What am I doing wrong and what should I be doing?

Thanks

Comment: First.  Please Capitalize class names.  Second.  Why are you not using class-level variables in the first place?  Your `var1` is not an instance variable.  Why are you avoiding ordinary instance variables?

Comment: What is an instance variable?

Comment: That's a whole new question. 1. Actually do the **entire** Python tutorial.  2.  Search for "Python Instance Variable".  3.  Ask the question again, after doing the entire tutorial and reading the hundreds of web pages on Python instance variables.  It's a fundamental concept, and hard to cover in a comment on an unrelated question.

Answer (score 6):

```
class class2:
    var2 = class1.var1
```

This is a COPY of the current value of `class1.var1`.

> "I need to get a variable from the first class and use it in the second"

Use `class1.var1` instead of making a copy of the current value in `var2`.

Comment: OH so when i change var1, var2 is still pointing to what var1 unsed to be? 
Now that makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Very useful article which will help to understand variables in python and how to make correct copies of them: http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list

Answer (score 0):

All information on how variables are coppied is true, and the recommended article is well explained. But if you use `class1.var1` you will never get the value og the `self.var1` from `class1`. You can check why with the following code:

```
class Class1 :
var1 = 0
def meth1 (self):
    self.var1 += 1
    print(id(self.var1))

class Class2:
def meth2 (self):
    print(id(Class1.var1))

obj1 = Class1()
obj2 = Class2()

obj1.meth1()
obj2.meth2()
```

Where you get different ids for `Class1.var1` ( which is `var1` in line 2) and `self.var1`.

If you want to get the value of `self.var1` from `Class2`, you must initialize `var1` outside the class, and make it global inside the function where you add it a number:

```
var1 = 0
class class1 :

    def meth1 (self):
        global var1
        var1 += 1

class class2:

    def meth2 (self):
        print(var1)

obj1 = class1()
obj2 = class2()

obj1.meth1()
obj2.meth2()
```